# How to split a 3D grid of coordinate values into blocks in PyTorch?

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch

If I have a batch of uniform 3D grids of coordinate locations, with shape (for example), [1, 32, 32, 32, 3], what is the best way for me to split this up into multiple even chunks, so I could end up with something such as [1, 4096, 2, 2, 2, 3]? In other words, I’m splitting up that one big 32 x 32 x 32 cube where each point is an x, y, z coordinate location into 4096 smaller 2 x 2 x 2 cubes? Does a simple view operation make sense here, or would it throw off the coordinate values? I was looking into operations like torch.chunk, but they require a specific dimension to split along, which I’m not sure applies here.

My use case for this is that I have a smaller [1, 16, 16, 16, 3] cube, so I’m trying to match up points from this smaller shape into the corresponding cubes in the upsampled [1, 32, 32, 32, 3] shape (since a single coordinate point in the 16^3 shape corresponds to 8 points in the 32^3 shape).

For additional context, this is how I generate my 3D grid right now:

```
pxs = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 32)
pys = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 32)
pzs = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 32)

pxs = pxs.view(-1, 1, 1).expand(*shape).contiguous().view(size)
pys = pys.view(1, -1, 1).expand(*shape).contiguous().view(size)
pzs = pzs.view(1, 1, -1).expand(*shape).contiguous().view(size)
points = torch.stack([pxs, pys, pzs], dim=1)

grid_3d = torch.reshape(points, (32, 32, 32, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `reshape` it with the dimensions you'd like:

```
In [29]: lin = np.linspace(-1, 1, 32)
    ...: cube = np.stack(np.meshgrid(lin, lin, lin), axis=-1)
    ...: cube.shape
Out[29]: (32, 32, 32, 3)

In [30]: new_cube = cube.reshape((1, 4096, 2, 2, 2, 3))
    ...: new_cube.shape
Out[30]: (1, 4096, 2, 2, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This was what I was originally considering as well, but I'm not sure if it preserves the locations of the coordinates. For example, what I'm imagining is that if I have a 3D grid of coordinate points, then each sub-cube will be a cube of neighboring points. However, I'm not sure how much that depends on how I initialize my original 3D coordinate grid to begin with. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer may help you

```py
def meshgrid3D(B, D, H, W, device='cuda'):
    """
    :param device: 
    :param B:
    :param H:
    :param W:
    :return:
    """
    grid_x = torch.arange(0, W, device=device).view(1, 1, -1).repeat(D, H, 1)
    grid_y = torch.arange(0, H, device=device).view(1, -1, 1).repeat(D, 1, W)
    grid_z = torch.arange(0, D, device=device).view(-1, 1, 1).repeat(1, H, W)

    # grid_x, grid_y, grid_z = torch.meshgrid(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z)
    # grid_x = grid_x.permute(1, 0, 2)
    # grid_y = grid_y.permute(1, 0, 2)
    # grid_z = grid_z.permute(1, 0, 2)
    grid_x = grid_x.view(1, 1, D, H, W).repeat(B, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    grid_y = grid_y.view(1, 1, D, H, W).repeat(B, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    grid_z = grid_z.view(1, 1, D, H, W).repeat(B, 1, 1, 1, 1)

    grid = torch.cat((grid_x, grid_y, grid_z), 1).float()  # [B,Coords=3,W,H,D]
    return grid
```